# could someone provide solution to exorcism of human to human possession? remove astral attachment of another human being?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, atma

if astral travel is possible and then human soul can enter another living human..is there any way to remove that astral body of another living human being which has entered you? hope i have simplified the question and is clear

Comment: Mentally (or physically) chanting and remembering some intense forms of Lords like Bhairava, Narasimha, Chandika, etc.. could be useful in such case! Also various Kavacha stotras of various deities are available which offer protection from every direction!

Comment: Mehendipur Balaji temple in Rajasthan